# Instagram's fade effect

Tags: image-processing

What is the pixel-level explanation of the fade effect, that was first popularized by Instagram? I want to implement this effect programmatically—that is, I want to understand what this effect is doing to each pixel.

[image]

Also, if anyone could point me to resources from which I can learn more about how image filters are implemented, that would be great.

Comment: Very easy way to achieve a similar look is to just add a small value to the color or each pixel, then clamp to max (255 or 1). It will make the image look more "washed out".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The effect in the photo is very close to a simple scale-bias per pixel. After a bit of tweaking, I found that applying the transformation: $x' = 0.77x + 38$ to the raw pixel values (as bytes) gives something quite close to your output:

[image: transformed image]

In this case the effect of the scale-bias is to reduce the contrast (scale factor < 1) while keeping the overall brightness about the same.

Example Python code (with numpy and pillow) to do this transformation:

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
a = np.array(Image.open("input.png"), dtype=np.float32)
b = a * 0.77 + 38
Image.fromarray(np.uint8(np.rint(b))).save("output.png")
```

For learning how to implement many basic image processing operations, I've found these [Image Processing Operator Worksheets](http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/rbf/HIPR2/wksheets.htm) from the University of Edinburgh helpful.